# Better way to convert OrderedDictionary to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

How do you convert from `OrderedDictionary` to `Dictionary<string, string>` in a concise, yet performant way?

**The Situation:**

I have a library that I can't touch that expects me to pass a `Dictionary<string, string>`. I want to build up an `OrderedDictionary` though, because order is so important in my part of the code. So, I'm working with an `OrderedDictionary` and when it comes time to hit the library, I need to convert it to `Dictionary<string, string>`.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var enumerator = MyOrderedDictionary.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    dict.Add(enumerator.Key as string, enumerator.Value as string);
}
```

There's got to be room for improvement here. Is there a more concise way of performing this conversion? Any performance considerations?

I'm using .NET 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just two improvements to your code. First, you can use `foreach` instead of `while`. This will hide details of GetEnumerator.

Second, you can preallocate required space in the target dictionary, since you know how many items you are going to copy.

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

class App
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var myOrderedDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();
    myOrderedDictionary["A"] = "1";
    myOrderedDictionary["B"] = "2";
    myOrderedDictionary["C"] = "3";
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(myOrderedDictionary.Count);
    foreach(DictionaryEntry kvp in myOrderedDictionary)
    {
      dict.Add(kvp.Key as string, kvp.Value as string);
    }
  }

}
```

An alternative approach is using LINQ, to convert dictionary in-place, if you want a new instance
of the dictionary, and not populate some existing one:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var dict = myOrderedDictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
.ToDictionary(k => (string)k.Key, v=> (string)v.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried `foreach` right off the bat, but couldn't figure out how to get `.Key` and `.Value`, but I was using `var kvp` instead of `DictionaryEntry kvp`. Looks good now. I also like the linq approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a generic [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) instead,  you can simply use the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` constructor that takes an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` argument:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(MyOrderedDictionary);
```

**Note:** You will *not* be able to use the same class to maintain the order and be derived from `Dictionary` because the methods in `Dictionary` are not virtual. The library creator should have used `IDictionary` instead of `Dictionary` on the publicly exposed library methods, but they didn't so now you have to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did see that constructor for dictionary that takes a `SortedDictionary`. I'm just not sure if it is a problem for the keys to be sorted in my situation. At least it guarantees order. This might be the route I go. Also, thank you for wording my frustration on the library so well. It is an unfortunate situation.